# Does Exchange Web Services 2016+ support Kerboros?

Tags: exchangewebservices

Kerboros is no longer listed in the auth mechanisms for EWS- is Kerboros still supported? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/authentication-and-ews-in-exchange

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does the documentation is using older terminology. IIS which is what EWS runs on the top of supports Anonymous, Basic and Integrated Authentication as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff647076(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

> Integrated Windows. Integrated Windows authentication (formerly called NTLM, and also known as Windows NT Challenge/Response authentication) uses either Kerberos v5 authentication or NTLM authentication, depending upon the client and server configuration. The server negotiates with the client to determine the protocol to use.

Intergrated Windows Auth can be eithier NTLM or Kerberos but generally from a domain connected workstation/server it will be Kerberos while other clients that can't negotiate Kerberos will use NTLM.